# Why does a broad-phrase rank better than new optimized exact-phrase?

Tags: seo, google, keywords, ranking

I will explain what happened:

I have this site that ranked first for "**estructuras truss**":

[See Google Result](http://www.google.es/#hl=es&pq=site%3ahttp://www.iddeasp.com/alquiler-estructura-truss-y-venta&xhr=t&q=Estructuras+truss&cp=18&pf=p&sclient=psy&source=hp&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=Estructuras+truss+&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=7bd1b4183091bc5e&biw=1522&bih=706) (mail.iddeasp.com/truss-alquiler-y-venta-de-estructuras) iddea sp

> **Truss: Alquiler y Venta de Estructuras | iddea SP**
>   ***El truss es una estructura de aluminio de diseño moderno y
>   tecnológico con un ...   La gran
>   ventaja en el montaje y desmontaje de
>   las estructuras truss es que ...
>
>   mail.iddeasp.com/truss-alquiler-y-venta-de-estructuras***

I've modified this page in order to have "estructuras truss" as an exact phrase... and Google didn't even bother to rank that page.

The new page is

http://www.iddeasp.com/alquiler-estructura-truss-y-venta

> **Alquiler Estructura Truss y Venta | iddea SP**
>   ***Estructuras truss: estructuras de aluminio ligeras y económicas. Se
>   alquilan o compran para crear
>   cualquier estructura o montaje
>   efímero: el mejor sistema ...***

This page is not listed in even in the top 100 on google.

I got lucky because as I'm using Drupal ... the old page remained somehow in cache and Google still finds it...still it's cached in March and the new page I've created it a week ago, 30th of May..

Anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The ['new page'](http://www.iddeasp.com/alquiler-estructura-truss-y-venta) you link to returns an error message: 'The page you requested does not exist.' Could you edit your question to include the correct link to the second page?

Answer (score 1):

Google ranks things by more than just keywords. It also includes how many links there are to a page. Your brand new page may have no links to it. I would add a 301 redirect from the old to the new page so that search engines know that it's moved.

Comment: I've actually created an alias that's the old page, that shows the new one, as Drupal allows this easily. I've checked and no links to this specific page existed previously.. Still the sitemap.xml didn't have the new page, nor the priority of the main sections of the site (including this one) was not bigger. Is there any other way to "tell" google which are my primary pages?

Comment: Were internal links on your site to the old page? Are there links to the new one now? Apart from using the sitemap Google tries to work out from the way you structure your pages what the structure of your site is. So a menu that is on every page is a good clue that those menu items point to key parts of the site.

Answer (score 0):

You have many broken links in your site.The page itself does not exist.
Moreover try adding not more than 100 links in your site and possibly add one page each day.This will help you up to an extent.